# Зачем нужен PRIMARY KEY и FOREIGN KEY (ключи)?

Tags: sql

Вот пример

```
CREATE TABLE instructor (
  ID CHAR(5),
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department(dept_name)
);
```

Разумеется, я читал основы SQL, но они не объясняют зачем нужны эти ключи в работе БД.
Первичный ключ ID содержит уникальное значение по которому можно однозначно идентифицировать запись.

Тут первичный ключ ID. Внешний ключ dept_name.
Зачем мы пишем перед полем PRIMARY KEY т.е. указываем что это поле первичный ключ? Почему нельзя сделать это поле просто автоинкрементируемым? И будет уникальное поле.

Аналогично - зачем мы пишем перед полем dept_name FOREIGN KEY? То есть мы говорим, что поле dept_name указывает на поле dept_name в другой таблице department. Что это дает?

Я могу не указывать FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department(dept_name) при создании таблицы. Просто запомнить, что например JOIN по этим полям.

Что делают эти команды? Зачем они нужны?

Comment: О какой СУБД речь?

Comment: Автоинкрементируемое поле можно изменить UPDATE-запросом, и есть риск, что оно перестанет быть уникальным. PRIMARY KEY не позволит изменить его на уникальное значение

Comment: FOREIGN KEY запретит удаление строки́ из department, если в instructor ещё есть стро́ки, которые ссылаются на строку, которую пытались удалить

Comment: @andreymal Или удалять все записи по ключу из таблицы instructor. В то же время запретят вставку записей в instructor если в department нет соответствующего ключа

Comment: *Почему нельзя сделать это поле просто автоинкрементируемым? И будет уникальное поле.* Можно. Только в этом случае ничто не мешает сунуть в это поле NULL... в сотню записей.

Answer (score 4):

Либо плохо читали, либо читали что-то не то. По пунктам.

PRIMARY KEY. Как выше уже сказали, identity-поле вовсе не гарантирует уникальность значения. Пример ниже - для MS SQL.
Создаем таблицу, и добавляем в неё 1 строку:

```
use tempdb
go
create table dbo.pk_test (
  id int identity not null,
  name varchar(1)
)
go
insert into dbo.pk_test(name) values('A');
select id, name from dbo.pk_test;
go

id          name
----------- ----
          1 A

(1 rows affected)
```

и вставляем ещё одну с таким же id:

```
begin tran;
set xact_abort on;
set identity_insert dbo.pk_test on;
insert into dbo.pk_test(id, name) values(1, 'B');
set identity_insert dbo.pk_test off;
select id, name from dbo.pk_test;
go

id          name
----------- ----
          1 A
          1 B

(2 rows affected)
```

– никаких ошибок.
Откатываем вставку, вешаем на поле id PRIMARY KEY:

```
rollback
go
alter table dbo.pk_test add constraint pk_pk_test primary key(id);
go
select id, name from dbo.pk_test;
go

id          name
----------- ----
          1 A

(1 rows affected)
```

и снова пытаемся вставить дубль id:

```
begin tran;
set xact_abort on;
set identity_insert dbo.pk_test on;
insert into dbo.pk_test(id, name) values(1, 'B');
go

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_pk_test'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.pk_test'.
```

– получаем ошибку.
А в некоторых БД identity-поля отсутствуют вообще - например, в оракле до версии 12c. Вместо них используются генераторы последовательностей (sequence), и для вставки неуникального значения в поле не нужно никаких ухищрений типа set identity_insert.
И ещё нюанс PRIMARY/UNIQUE constraints: по сути, это логические ограничения, ограничения бизнес-модели. На физическом уровне эти ограничения всегда реализуются уникальными индексами по соответствующим полям.

FOREIGN KEY: создаем и заполняем тестовые таблицы:

```
use tempdb
go
create table dbo.fk_source (
  id int not null primary key
)
go
create table dbo.fk_target (
  fk_id int not null,
  constraint fk_target_source foreign key(fk_id) references dbo.fk_source(id)
    on update cascade on delete no action
)
go
insert into dbo.fk_source(id) values(1);
insert into dbo.fk_target(fk_id) values(1);
go
select id from dbo.fk_source;
go

id
-----------
          1

(1 rows affected)

select fk_id from dbo.fk_target;
go

fk_id
-----------
          1
(1 rows affected)
```

теперь в таблице, на которую ссылается FK, меняем значение поля с FK:

```
update dbo.fk_source set id=2 where id=1;
go

(1 rows affected)

select fk_id from dbo.fk_target
go

fk_id
-----------
          2
(1 rows affected)
```

– из-за включенной опции каскадного обновления в связанной таблице значение поля обновилось автоматически.
Пытаемся удалить запись из таблицы-источника:

```
delete dbo.fk_source where id=2;
go

Msg 547, Level 16, State 1, Server ., Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_target_source".
  The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.fk_target", column 'fk_id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

– FK не позволяет этого сделать.
Пытаемся в таблицу-приёмник вставить не существующее в таблице-источнике значение:

```
insert into dbo.fk_target(fk_id) values(3);
go

Msg 547, Level 16, State 1, Server ., Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_target_source".
  The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.fk_source", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

– FK не позволяет этого сделать.
Пытаемся очистить всю таблицу-источник, и вообще удалить её:

```
truncate table dbo.fk_source;
go

Msg 4712, Level 16, State 1, Server ., Line 1
Cannot truncate table 'dbo.fk_source' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

drop table dbo.fk_source;
go

Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Server ., Line 1
Could not drop object 'dbo.fk_source' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

– FK не позволяет этого сделать.
А теперь удаляем FK:

```
alter table dbo.fk_target drop constraint fk_target_source
go
```

– и становится можно всё:

```
insert into dbo.fk_target(fk_id) values(3);
go

(1 rows affected)

delete dbo.fk_source where id=2;
go

(1 rows affected)

truncate table dbo.fk_source;
go
drop table dbo.fk_source;
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Помимо вышеуказанных причин приведу ещё одну: `PRIMARY KEY` и `FOREIGN KEY` зачастую индексируются. Это приводит к тому, что обращение по ним будет происходить быстрее.

Пример на MySql:

Создадим таблицу и заполним её большим числом данных:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_test_1` (
    `field_1` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field_2` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `field_3` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`field_1`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) VALUES ('a1'),('a2'),('a3');
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) VALUES ('b1'),('b2'),('b3');
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;
INSERT INTO `table_test_1` (`field_3`) SELECT `field_3` FROM `table_test_1`;

UPDATE `table_test_1` SET `field_2` = `field_1`;
```

Теперь у нас есть таблица с первичным ключом `field_1` и аналогичным ему значением `field_2`. Теперь сравним выборки по первичному ключу:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_test_1` WHERE `field_1` = 555555;
+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  555555 |  555555 | b2      |
+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

И по значению:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_test_1` WHERE `field_2` = 555555;
+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  555555 |  555555 | b2      |
+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.36 sec)
```

Разница заметна.

Теперь создадим вторую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_test_2` (
    `field_1` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field_2` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `field_3` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`field_1`),
    CONSTRAINT `table_test_2_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`field_3`) REFERENCES `table_test_1` (`field_1`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO `table_test_2` (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`) SELECT `field_1`, `field_1` FROM `table_test_1`;
```

Здесь у нас есть внешний ключ `field_3` и обычное поле `field_2`, значения которых содержит значения `field_1` (и соответственно `field_2`) из первой таблицы.

Попробуем `INNER JOIN` запрос на основе внешнего ключа:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_test_2` INNER JOIN `table_test_1` ON `table_test_2`.`field_3` = `table_test_1`.`field_1` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 55555;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   71925 |   71925 |   71925 |   71925 |   71925 | a2      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

А вот запрос на основе обычных значений:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_test_2` INNER JOIN `table_test_1` ON `table_test_2`.`field_2` = `table_test_1`.`field_2` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 55555;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   71925 |   71925 |   71925 |   71925 |   71925 | a2      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.51 sec)
```

Возможно эти примеры не самые показательные, но разница заметна уже на них, а для сложных структур данных и для более сложных запросов разница между индексируемыми значениями и неиндексируемыми становится критически важной.

Answer (score 1):

Рассматривать надо с обратной стороны.

### Простой индекс.

Дополнительная структура, хранящая указанное выражение для каждой записи, причём в сортированном порядке. Ускоряет выполнение многих операций, во-первых, за счёт более компактного по сравнению с самой таблицей размера (т.е. требует меньше чтений), во-вторых, за счёт сортированности по выражению индекса.

### Уникальный индекс.

Отличается от обычного дополнительным условием уникальности выражения для каждой записи. В дополнение к функциям простого индекса обеспечивает быстрый контроль уникальности и не позволяет появляться дубликатам в данных. Однако при наличии NULL в любом из полей выражения не считает такие записи дубликатами (это не относится, например, к OracleDB, которая не различает NULL и пустую строку).

### Первичный индекс.

Отличается дополнительным условием запрета значения NULL в полях, использованных в выражении индекса. За счёт этого обеспечивает максимально строгий контроль отсутствия дубликатов, а потому может использоваться (и используется) для уникальной идентификации записи. В некоторых СУБД (например, MySQL/MariaDB) первичный индекс, кроме того, безусловно является кластерным.

---

А внешний ключ (FOREIGN KEY) - это вообще не структура. Это правило. Правило контроля. Сервер при любом изменении данных проверяет, чтобы оно не было нарушено.

Кстати, для того, чтобы быстро проверять - должен существовать индекс.

Comment: Безусловно является кластерным - и это не регулируется? В MSSQL для PK можно задавать опцию CLUSTERED/NONCLUSTERED (по умолчанию значение CLUSTERED).

Comment: @user11354240 Зависит от СУБД - в каждой по-своему.

Answer (score 0):

У обеих конструкций две основные задачи:

1. Поддержание целостности
2. Самодокументирование кода

`PRIMARY KEY` гарантирует, что в столбце все значения будут уникальными, вне зависимости от того, как вы их генерируете.

`FOREIGN KEY` гарантирует, что значение из таблицы точно есть в той таблице, на которую идёт ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Первичный ключ (PRIMARY KEY) - это одному или нескольким столбцам таблицы, которые используются для уникальной идентификации каждой строки таблицы. Он обычно создается с целью обеспечения целостности данных и упрощения связей с другими таблицами. Вы можете сделать поле автоинкрементируемым, но это не является рекомендуемым способом создания первичного ключа. Это может привести к проблемам с целостностью данных, если в какой-то момент вы захотите изменить структуру таблицы или импортировать данные из другой таблицы.

Внешний ключ (FOREIGN KEY) - это столбец или столбцы, которые ссылаются на первичный ключ другой таблицы. Они часто используются для установления связи между таблицами

В таблице instructor внешний ключ dept_name ссылается на первичный ключ dept_name в таблице department. Это означает, что значение dept_name в таблице instructor должно существовать в таблице department. Это помогает обеспечить целостность данных, так как предотвращает внесение несуществующих значений в таблицу instructor.

Определение внешнего ключа также позволяет создавать связи между таблицами при использовании оператора JOIN. Например, можно использовать JOIN, чтобы получить все инструкторы, преподающие в каком-то отделении, и информацию об этом отделении.

В общем, использование первичных и внешних ключей помогает создавать целостные и связанные таблицы, что упрощает работу с ними и обеспечивает целостность данных.

Ниже приведены несколько примеров использования первичных и внешних ключей.

## Пример 1

Предположим, у нас есть таблицы customers и orders. Таблица orders содержит информацию о заказах клиентов, а таблица customers содержит информацию о клиентах. Мы хотим, чтобы каждый заказ был связан с определенным клиентом, поэтому в таблице orders мы можем создать внешний ключ customer_id, который ссылается на первичный ключ id в таблице customers. Таким образом, мы можем убедиться, что в таблице orders не будут указаны несуществующие клиенты.

## Пример 2

Предположим, у нас есть таблицы products и orders. Таблица products содержит информацию о товарах, а таблица orders содержит информацию о заказах. Мы хотим, чтобы каждый заказ содержал информацию о конкретном товаре.

---

Вернёмся к instructor с использованием первичного ключа и внешнего ключа:

```
CREATE TABLE instructor (
  ID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department(dept_name)
);
```

В этой таблице ID является первичным ключом, то есть уникальным идентификатором для каждой строки таблицы. Поле dept_name является внешним ключом, которое ссылается на поле dept_name в таблице department. Это означает, что значение dept_name в таблице instructor должно существовать в таблице department.

## Некоторые примеры SQL-запросов, использующих таблицу instructor

Вставка новой строки в таблицу instructor:

```
INSERT INTO instructor (ID, name, dept_name) VALUES ('12345', 'John Smith', 'Computer Science');
```

Обновление информации об инструкторе:

```
UPDATE instructor SET name = 'Jane Smith' WHERE ID = '12345';
```

Получение списка всех инструкторов в отделении Computer Science:

```
SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE dept_name = 'Computer Science';
```

Получение списка всех инструкторов с информацией об их отделениях:

```
SELECT instructor.name, department.dept_name
FROM instructor
JOIN department ON instructor.dept_name = department.dept_name;
```

Получение списка инструкторов, которые преподают в отделении Computer Science, отсортированных по имени:

```
SELECT * FROM instructor
WHERE dept_name = 'Computer Science'
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Удаление всех инструкторов из отделения Mathematics:

```
DELETE FROM instructor
WHERE dept_name = 'Mathematics';
```

Эти примеры дают некоторое представление о том, как можно использовать первичные и внешние ключи в таблице instructor. Однако, это далеко не все возможности, которые предлагают первичные и внешние ключи, и вы можете использовать их в различных ситуациях для управления данными в вашей базе данных.

## Несколько примеров SQL-запросов, которые, скорее всего, не будут выполнены из-за нарушения целостности данных

Вставка строки в таблицу instructor с несуществующим значением внешнего ключа dept_name:

```
INSERT INTO instructor (ID, name, dept_name) VALUES ('12345', 'John Smith', 'Physics');
```

Если в таблице department нет отделения с именем 'Physics', то этот запрос не будет выполнен, так как внешний ключ dept_name в таблице instructor должен ссылаться на существующее отделение в таблице department.

Обновление строки в таблице instructor с несуществующим значением первичного ключа ID:

```
UPDATE instructor SET name = 'Jane Smith' WHERE ID = '54321';
```

Если в таблице instructor нет строки с ID '54321', то этот запрос не будет выполнен, так как первичный ключ ID должен существовать в таблице.

Удаление строки из таблицы instructor с несуществующим значением первичного ключа:

```
DELETE FROM instructor
WHERE ID = '54321';
```

Если в таблице instructor нет строки с ID '54321', то этот запрос не будет выполнен, так как первичный ключ ID должен существовать в таблице.

Эти примеры показывают, что первичные и внешние ключи используются для обеспечения целостности данных в базе данных. Они запрещают внесение некорректных данных в таблицы и служат механизмом защиты от ошибок.